# IoC container property inheritance

Tags: spring, inversion-of-control

I have a number of Spring files that depend on property placeholders in other files. Essentially, I have 3 XML files like so:

**one.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<beans ...>

    <import resource="two.xml"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/your.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="clasher" class="whatever.Clash">
        <property name="name" value="${route.one}"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**two.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<beans ...>

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/my.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**my.properties**:

```
route.one = Why Not?
```

**your.properties**:

```
entirely.unrelated = true
```

I'm getting an error that essentially looks like this:

```
Exception in thread "Launcher:/serverling" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'clasher' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/one.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'route.one'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.processProperties(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:75)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:663)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:638)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:407)
    at org.red5.server.tomcat.TomcatLoader$1.run(TomcatLoader.java:594)
```

Is there a way to make property placeholders inherit across the entire container?

My initial assumption was that since the container didn't really care which file beans lived in, it would simply configure all the beans then run through all defined beans in the container and use the multiple property placeholder configurers to fill them in.

Why isn't this example workingL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set this flag for `PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer`:

```
<property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply give each bean of `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` an ID (or at least one of them) and it should be fine. My guess is that one overrides the other when no Bean ID is declared and that's why you lose some property values. If you're using it under annotation-based text contexts, consider [this issue](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-5456). [Here](http://www.cwinters.com/blog/2005/07/26/multiple_separate_propertyplaceholderconfigurers_in_spring.html) also demonstrates a more fine-tuned usage of multiple instances of property configurer.